# Calculate age based on multiple fields

Tags: sql, date, datetime, time, google-bigquery

I have a table with a date of birth column, a date of death column and the date the dataset was extracted.

I want to calculate each person's age as either the date of their death or their age at the date of extract - not by the current date - with a new 'Age' column. I can't quite work it out at the moment.

Example data:

**Current table**

| person_id | birth_datetimetime | death_datetime | extract_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1980-04-01T00:00:00 | null | 2021-12-31 |
| 8765 | 1925-05-04T00:00:00 | 2018-05-T00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 |
| 9102 | 1974-05-17T00:00:00 | 2021-01-31T00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 |
| 5678 | 2019-09-01T00:00:00 | null | 2021-12-31 |
| 3456 | 1947-04-01T00:00:00 | 2016-06-14T00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 |

**Desired output**

| person_id | birth_datetimetime | death_datetime | extract_date | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 1980-04-01T00:00:00 | null | 2021-12-31 | 41 |
| 8765 | 1925-05-04T00:00:00 | 2018-05-T00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 | 93 |
| 9102 | 1974-05-17T00:00:00 | 2021-01-31T00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 | 47 |
| 5678 | 2019-09-01T00:00:00 | null | 2021-12-31 | 2 |
| 3456 | 1947-04-01T00:00:00 | 2016-06-14T00:00:00 | 2021-12-31 | 69 |

Comment: Desired output in second row date of birth  `1925-05-04T00:00:00` and date of death is `2018-05-T00:00:00` it not understand can you explain.

Comment: How 'accurate' does the Age calculation need to be?  If someone is born `2020-12-31` and dies on `2021-01-01`, they're really 0 years and 1 day old, but some calculations would say the two dates are in different years and therefore yield a 1 year difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select *, 
  date_diff(ifnull(death_datetime, extract_date), date(birth_datetimetime), year) as age
from your_table
```

if applied to sample data in your question  - output is

[image]

Comment: Row 2's DoB is 4th May, but they died on 1st May, so they should be 92 with that data set.

Comment: Desired output in second row date of birth 1925-05-04T00:00:00 and date of death is 2018-05-T00:00:00 it not understand can you explain.

Comment: i think `2018-05-T00:00:00` is a typo, so I just replaced it with `2018-05-01T00:00:00`

Comment: Don't worry, I just made those up for illustration purposes.

Comment: @MatBailie - agree with you, formally it should be 92. Similarly for third row - it should be 46. But looked to me that OP's "rounding" logic required 47, so I 've chosen not to overcomplicate stuff :o)